# My page doesnt see css files on localhost

Tags: html, css

I set up a simple php page in localhost with uwamp.

My css link is like:  css/style.css

The page doesnt see this. But if i view the site source in chrome, and open the css file from there with the link, it opens right.

What am i doing wrong?

```
    <link href="css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="textcss">
<link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="textcss">
<link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="textcss">
```

Comment: have you tried with <link href="~/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

Comment: HI its sometime issues with firewall please try to off than check it.

Comment: The uwamp is cheked in the firewall, thats not problem.

Comment: @Bharat , yes i tried, but nothing.

Comment: @user7722712 :  try again..with my code..you have tyypo..

Answer (score 1):

Remove  `type="textcss"` in your includes or change it to `type="text/css"`

Answer (score 0):

you need to change type element value `type="text/css"`
you written wrong..

Answer (score 0):

this is wrong type="textcss" please use this  type="text/css"